# Track user-id in button click - google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I would like to track a button click event on my wordpress site. But i want the info in such a way that how many clicks were made by a particular user. Can i pass user-id from my website and get the number of clicks for the user-ids?

Comment: Where are you getting the user-id from? Do you require your users to be logged in on your wordpress site?

Comment: yes the users will be logged in.

Answer (score 3):

I'd split this out into two areas: (1) tracking the button click, and (2) collecting data by user. For tracking the button click, I would recommend [Event Tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en). For collecting data by user, I would recommend passing in a non personally identifiable user ID as a [user-scoped custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#example-user). Then, you'll be able to create a flat table custom report with your custom dimension and event category as dimensions, and total events as a metric. Then you can see events per user.

One additional note here, you might want to explore using the [User ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/user-id-overview) feature, which allows you to measure logged in users across browsers and devices. But even if you use the User ID feature, you'll still need to use custom dimensions to see data by User ID.

Comment: Hi is there any example coding implementation for this?

Comment: Do i need universal analytics to implement custom dimensions and metric?

Comment: You will need Universal Analytics (UA) for custom dimensions and metrics, but if you are not using UA you can use a custom variable instead. [example code for custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) and [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)

Comment: Thank you. But i  have used event tracking code to achieve the result. I have answered above.

Answer (score 1):

I have find a solution for this. I have used event tracking to achieve this. I have used the following function in the click event of the button.

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','button-category','Click','Clicked by the user:User id from my site']);

In the label field i pass the user id from my site. Now, i can see the clicks of a particular user using his id under Behavior->Events->Pages->Your Page->Event Category->Event Action->Event Label. As username is personally identifiable info according to google, i didn't use username.

Comment: You are just passing this value as label. Is there any other way if we didn't pass this value in label but initialised the google analytics object with userid